# How to create a readonly root linux: Can be mounted as writeable for persistent changes?

Tags: linux, read-only, embedded-linux

I'd like a read only file system that runs almost entirely in RAM but the compact flash or hardrive can be mounted and made writeable to make persistent changes.

How do I do this on Linux? I've looked at several tutorials but none really explain how to create such a system with the option of being able to mount the storage device and make persistent changes.

I looked at this so far: http://chschneider.eu/linux/thin_client/
I also looked on the old gentoo wiki but the article was very specific to Gentoo. I'll be using a debian based Linux but it would be nice I've someone could explain to me how to do this in pretty generic instructions ,that would work on any Linux distro.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a normal file system on the CF or HD. Mount it read only in fstab. Remount it RW if you need to make updates/changes. Remount to RO when you're done. Let the kernel worry about RAM caching.